# Show toastr once after succesful login

Tags: jquery, toastr

I want to show only once `toastr` notification after the user has a successful login.
If the user tried to reload the page or the user redirect to another page, I don't want to reshow the notification.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with `local.storage()`:

[Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
var isLogged = localStorage.getItem("isLogged");

if(!isLogged){
    alert('notification');
}

localStorage.setItem("isLogged", true);


//on logout or window.onbeforeunload remove from local storage
//localStorage.removeItem("isLogged");
```

Example: [localStorage example](https://jsfiddle.net/28jxsm4r/)

NOTE: to check stored items go to browser console under Application tab Local Storage section

Comment: Thank you. That gives me idea. hehe